# QT Flowlayout - issue with multiline labels

Tags: qt, flowlayout

I have a small problem with QT layout.

I have a toolbox, and I want to populate it with some checkable buttons with a description. So I create a `QWidget` with a `QGridLayout` and put the `QButton` in the first cell and the `QLabel` in the second.

This is the most important part of the code (I removed dependancies from other irrelevant code in the app):

```
QWidget *createCellWidget()
{
    QToolButton *button = new QToolButton(this);
    button->setCheckable(true);
    button->setMinimumSize(57,57);
    button->setMaximumSize(57,57);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(widget);
    layout->addWidget(button, 0, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter);
    QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("my very long caption");
    lbl->setWordWrap(true);
    lbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    layout->addWidget(lbl, 1, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
    widget->setMaximumWidth(80);
    widget->setMinimumWidth(80);

    return widget;
}
```

then I create a `QGridLayout` and populate it with these controls:

```
QWidget *itemWidget_FlowControl = new QWidget(this);
QGridLayout *_flowControl_layout = new QGridLayout(itemWidget_FlowControl);
_flowControl_layout->addWidget(createCellWidget(), 0, 0);
```

This works well and produces this output:

[image: Widgets properly aligned]

this is a nice layout. Unluckily if I enlarge the window the controls do not "flow", so I tried to replace the QGridLayout with a flowlayout ([here are the source files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html)).

Now the behavior is much better. BUT...

[image: Widgets not alignet]

this is what I get. The longer captions are laid out as if they were single-lined, so the text overlaps with the button.

What can I do to make it look like before, but keeping it as a "flow layout"? Or do you know if there is any alternative in QT 5.2?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What's wrong?

You are on the right track of using flowlayout.

The only problem is the **internal layouts** (`QGridLayout` in your case) of your cell widgets also stretch in response to the resize events.

---

### Solution

The solution is surprisingly simple:

> Try to **limit the stretch** of the internal layout.

Within the factory function `QWidget *createCellWidget()`:

**[Option 1]**

Add `lbl->setMaximumWidth(60);` to manually limit the stretch of label width. This makes the internal layout not stretch so "freely."

**[Option 2]**

Add `layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);` to restrain the internal layout stretch. By doing this, you may want to manually add some line break code (`\n`) to your "very long caption" in case the label width automatically decided by Qt doesn't suit your need.

---

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Option 2, as you said, needs manual new lines, since the captions are not split. So I chose option 1, which behaves exactly like what I needed. Now I just need to figure out how to center the widgets, but.. Thank you for helping me solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach would be use off style sheets (flow layout is Ok).
Simply use `QButton` but customize its view by altering its stye sheet.
Currently I have no time to write an example.