# Qt HBoxLayout - transitioning widgets to a new line

Tags: c++, qt

is there a way to configure QHBoxLayout, so when the added widgets(different in width) reach the end of the line, they would be added to a new line? How would you even detect if the last added widget crosses the end of the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with a `QHBoxLayout`, since there isn't the concept of "new line".

You can manually adjust a `QGridLayout`. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237206/qt-flowlayout-issue-with-multiline-labels) related question on SO.

Or you can use the Qt `FlowLayout`. It's not a built-in layout, but in [Qt FlowLayout Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) you can find an example with the implementation.